# Spring Data MongoDB sorting with nullsLast as a URL query parameter

Tags: spring, spring-data-mongodb

I'm using spring data MongoDB and trying to sort my results in a specific field in a specific direction and I want the null values to be the last.
The way I do that is sending the fields i want to sort in the URL as a query parameter something like the following:

```
/Resource?sort=date,asc
```

When the controller receives this request i can see the order cases in the Pageable attribute are filled correctly and the sorting is made automatically by the findAll(Pageable) method provided by spring data, the sorting is working fine, but if the date is null it will bring the Resources with a null date first, and I want the opposite.

Is there anyway to add a request parameter in the URL so the results will be ordered by date ASC and the null values at the last?
If not how can i achieve this ? maybe modifying the Pageable object but i there's no method such nullsLast()